# Polylang redirects to homepage when translation post not found - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, polylang

If the translation of the post is not available, Polylang redirects to the home page.

Could the redirect be avoided or show previous post?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the Wordpress menu tab then click on languages option and unselect the "Forces link to front page" option

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwt1a.png)